# transfer rate in ab apache benchmark

Tags: java, performance, undertow, apachebench

I am benchmarking a simple [helloworld](https://github.com/actframework/act-demo-apps/tree/master/helloworld) app written in my framework against the [one](https://github.com/hellokoding/springboot-freemarker) written in SpringBoot.

The ab log for SpringBoot version:

```
luog~$ ab -n 100000 -c 20 http://localhost:8080/hello?name=rythm
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1706008 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 10000 requests
Completed 20000 requests
Completed 30000 requests
Completed 40000 requests
Completed 50000 requests
Completed 60000 requests
Completed 70000 requests
Completed 80000 requests
Completed 90000 requests
Completed 100000 requests
Finished 100000 requests


Server Software:        Apache-Coyote/1.1
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /hello?name=rythm
Document Length:        155 bytes

Concurrency Level:      20
Time taken for tests:   6.733 seconds
Complete requests:      100000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      32100000 bytes
HTML transferred:       15500000 bytes
Requests per second:    14851.38 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1.347 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.067 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          4655.56 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.1      0       2
Processing:     0    1   0.7      1      15
Waiting:        0    1   0.7      1      15
Total:          0    1   0.7      1      15

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      1
  66%      1
  75%      2
  80%      2
  90%      2
  95%      2
  98%      3
  99%      4
 100%     15 (longest request)
```

And the ab log for ActFramework:

```
luog~$ ab -n 100000 -c 20 http://localhost:5460/?who=rythm
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1706008 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 10000 requests
Completed 20000 requests
Completed 30000 requests
Completed 40000 requests
Completed 50000 requests
Completed 60000 requests
Completed 70000 requests
Completed 80000 requests
Completed 90000 requests
Completed 100000 requests
Finished 100000 requests


Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            5460

Document Path:          /?who=rythm
Document Length:        111 bytes

Concurrency Level:      20
Time taken for tests:   6.796 seconds
Complete requests:      100000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      18600000 bytes
HTML transferred:       11100000 bytes
Requests per second:    14714.64 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1.359 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.068 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          2672.78 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       1
Processing:     0    1   1.2      1       9
Waiting:        0    1   1.2      1       9
Total:          0    1   1.2      1       9

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      1
  66%      2
  75%      2
  80%      3
  90%      3
  95%      3
  98%      4
  99%      4
 100%      9 (longest request)
```

As we can see the transactions per seconds are pretty much the same. However the Transfer rate is very different. SpringBoot version got over 4.5Kb/s, while Act version has only 2.7Kb/s.

I wonder

1. Why the response time is nearly the same while transfer rate is so different?
2. How to improve the transfer rate? I am using undertow as my network layer, should there be anything I can do to tune undertow? [Here](https://github.com/actframework/actframework/blob/master/src/main/java/act/xio/undertow/UndertowNetwork.java) is my code that creates undertow network layer

Comment: The number of processed requests is the same, but the responses are different, both in the contents and in HTTP headers. Hence the difference in the traffic, too.

Comment: yeah, shame I didn't spot that. Can you please put your comment into an answer so that I can give you the credential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of processed requests is the same, but the responses are different, both in the contents and in HTTP headers. Hence the difference in the traffic, too.